# Probability of the inside racer being the winner (finite dimensional distribution of Brownian motion)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> In a bicycle race between two competitors, let $Y(t)$ denote the amount of time (in seconds) by which the racer that started in the inside position is ahead when $100t$ percent of the race has been completed, $0\leq t\leq 1$. (So $t$ here does not quite have the meaning of time as we usually think it. Also if $Y(t)$ is negative this means the inside racer is behind). $Y(t,0\leq t \leq 1)$ can be effectively modeled as a Brownian motion with variance parameter $\sigma^2$.
>
> If the inside racer is leading by $\sigma$ seconds at the midpoint of the race, what is
> the probability that she is the winner?
>
> Source: [Rutgers Spring 2019 M478 (lecture 7) pgs. 3-4](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Etmp140/courses/Spring2019/M478/478-Lecture7.pdf)

### My Work So Far

\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}\left\{Y(1)\gt0\bigg|Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sigma\right\}\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left\{Y(1)-Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\gt-\sigma\bigg|Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sigma\right\}&&\text{(1) cancel RHS}\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left\{Y(1)-Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\gt-\sigma\right\}\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left\{Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\gt-\sigma\right\}\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left\{\frac{Y(1/2)}{\sigma/\sqrt{2}}\gt-\frac{\sigma}{{\sigma}/\sqrt{2}}\right\}&&\text{(2) divide LHS and RHS by}\  \sigma/\sqrt{2}\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left\{Z\gt-\sqrt{2}\right\}\\
&=\Phi(\sqrt{2})\\
&\approx0.9213\\
\end{align*}

```
pnorm(sqrt(2))
[1] 0.9213504
```

I believe the reason for $\text{(2)}$ is because we'd like to make the random variables on the LHS of the inequality a standard normal random variable, and that way we can use the normal CDF to finish our calculation via the $\Phi(x)$.

Would this method be correct?

The solution in the lecture notes stated the below, but I was unsure where the lines in red were derived from.
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}\left(Y(1)\gt0\bigg|Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sigma\right)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(Y(1)-Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\gt-\sigma\bigg|Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sigma\right)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(Y(1)-Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\gt-\sigma\right)\\
&\color{red}{=\mathbb{P}\left(N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)\gt-\sigma\right)}\\
&\color{red}{=\mathbb{P}\left(Z\gt-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma}\right)}\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance is proportional to the increment size [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922466/the-variance-of-brownian-motion#:%7E:text=Variance%20proportional%20to%20the%20increment%20size). Since $Y(1)$ follows a Brownian motion with variance $\sigma^2$, then $Y(1) - Y(\frac{1}{2})$ follows a Brownian motion with variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$, as you have halved the increment size.